# Failed to resolve: com.android.support after building gradle but my app can still be installed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have gone through all stackoverflow examples but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I tried to downgrade mz sdk vesrion and android:support but it didn't work. 
I am having the following code in build.gradle. However, whenever I try to build my gradle it shows an error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support... Anyway I am able to successfully install apk to my devices and it runs perfectly. I just don't want that his dependency will cause some error in the future. 
Thanks!

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.feecollector.android.feecollector"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.navigation_menu.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.navigation_menu:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.navigation_menu.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0'
}
```

Comment: what gradle version you are using

Comment: use latest gradle version why you are creating a project on lower gradle

Comment: I use Gradle version 3.1.4 which I think is the newest?

Comment: so why you use older library use latest :
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Comment: Same story. I also have to change compileSdkVersion from 27 - 28.

Answer (score 1):

You are using different versions of com.android.support.
this is your code:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

it should be like this:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I have already tried this but didn't find it as a solution, thanks anyway.

Comment: send the screen shot of your build.gradle file project level

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with gradle local setting. You can try to Invalidate and Restart cache. `Click File -> Invalidate caches`.

Sometimes you might even other issues with updating to new Gradle level. For this case, remove `.idea` and `.gradle` folders from Project Room and  **Import** it again from Idea start screen.

Comment: How to import it back again? I just built the project is that all?

Comment: I meant, whenever you have updated for the gradle. Rollback shouldn't help in this case. Try method above, it will gather all project and dependencies from the scrath.